# Java - error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i've a problem with an exercise of Thinking in Java. This is the code (this is the solution of the exercise) .

```
// object/StorageTest.java
// TIJ4 Chapter Object, Exercise 6, page 90
// Write a program that includes and calls the storage() method defined as a
// code fragment in this chapter.

public class StorageTest {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class StoreStuff {
            int storage(String s) {
                return s.length() * 2;
            }   
        }
        StoreStuff x = new StoreStuff();
        System.out.println(x.storage("hi"));        
    }
}
```

When i compile it, i've this error:

> C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop>javac StorageTest.java StorageTest.java:5:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                                   return (s.lenght()*2);
>                                            ^   symbol:   method lenght()   location: variable s of type String 1 error

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Why are your posting the solution if you have problems with your own code? Post your real code, not the one which is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mistyped `length()`. Even though in your code example it seems correct, in the error message it reads `lenght()`

Answer (score 1):

use this `return s.length() * 2;` and try to look at your code you have typos error `lenght()` should be `length()`